# Switch position of latitude and longitude in polygon using BigQuery

Tags: google-big-query

I have many polygons one example is like so

```
POLYGON ((-6.17635568766753 106.81217949327073, -6.177086740025682 106.81236308865992, -6.177909092611173 106.81256741425203, -6.178459760710375 106.81270423581032, -6.178946642579903 106.81282348367647,-6.17635568766753 106.81217949327073))
```

The position is all wrong so when I used ST_GEOGFROMTEXT in BigQuery it reads wrong.
How do I reverse the position so that the polygon becomes like so

```
POLYGON ((106.81217949327073 -6.17635568766753,  106.81236308865992 -6.177086740025682,  106.81256741425203 -6.177909092611173,  106.81270423581032 -6.178459760710375,  106.81282348367647 -6.178946642579903, 106.81217949327073 -6.17635568766753))
```

so that when I use ST_Within it's able to read the polygon data.

How can I do this in bigquery?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question.. Please [Edit] the Question to choose one of the two platforms (Python or BigQuery), and include your coding attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Use Python (list comprehension)

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.wkt import loads
poly = loads("POLYGON ((-6.17635568766753 106.81217949327073, -6.177086740025682 106.81236308865992, -6.177909092611173 106.81256741425203, -6.178459760710375 106.81270423581032, -6.178946642579903 106.81282348367647,-6.17635568766753 106.81217949327073)) ")
print(poly)
POLYGON ((-6.17635568766753 106.8121794932707, -6.177086740025682 106.8123630886599, -6.177909092611173 106.812567414252, -6.178459760710375 106.8127042358103, -6.178946642579903 106.8128234836765, -6.17635568766753 106.8121794932707))

ring = list(poly.exterior.coords)
new_ring = [(lat,lon) for (lon,lat) in ring]
poly2 = Polygon(new_ring)
print(poly2)
POLYGON ((106.8121794932707 -6.17635568766753, 106.8123630886599 -6.177086740025682, 106.812567414252 -6.177909092611173, 106.8127042358103 -6.178459760710375, 106.8128234836765 -6.178946642579903, 106.8121794932707 -6.17635568766753))
```

Comment: Less writing with "flip" https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354273/flipping-coordinates-with-shapely.